# Auto response after #seconds & #ofmessagelines

Tags: twitch, mirc

I want to count #ofmessagelines and #amountoftime that has passed.

Main script:

```
menu channel {
Announce
.Start: .timerAnnounce. $+ $chan 0 11 msg $chan $$?="Hi msg"
.Stop: .timerAnnounce. $+ $chan off
}
```

**Example given **

```
ON *:TEXT:*:#: {
if (%announce) {
inc %msgcounter 1
if (%msgcounter >= 10) {
if ($calc($ctime - %announce) >= 600) {
msg #chan YOur msg here
unset %msgcounter
set %announce $ctime
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to achieve ?